# How do I get the path from this maze algorithm with door and key in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search

I'm trying to learn DFS/BFS where I use DFS first. I think my code right now solves the problem but I would like to get the path from start to stop.

**Problem**:
It's the Maze problem where I need to go from start to stop coordinate where you can only travel on Land `'.'` . Here's the representation of the grid

```
'#' = Water
'.' = Land
'a' = Key of type 'a'
'A' = Door that opens with key 'a'
'@' = starting point
'+' = finish point.
```

Here's the example of the grid

```
['.', '.', '.', 'B']
['.', 'b', '#', '.']
['@', '#', '+', '.']
```

Here's my code so far

```
def find_shortest_path(grid):
    board = []
    for row in grid:
        column = []
        row = row.replace('\r', '')
        for c in row:
            column.append(c)
        board.append(column)

    ROW = len(board)
    COL = len(board[0])

    start = ()
    stop = ()
    key_set = {}

    # I can collapse this with the first loop
    for row in range(ROW):
        for col in range(COL):
            if board[row][col] == '@':
                start = (row, col)
            if board[row][col] == '+':
                stop = (row, col)
            if board[row][col].isalpha() and board[row][col].islower():
                key = board[row][col]
                key_set[key] = key_set.get(key, 0) + 1

    visited = [[False for _ in range(COL)] for _ in range(ROW)]

    def dfs(i, j):
        if i < 0 or i >= ROW \
                or j < 0 or j >= COL \
                or visited[i][j] \
                or board[i][j] == '#':
            return
        if i == stop[0] and j == stop[1]:
            print('end')
            return

        print('{}, {}'.format(i, j))

        if board[i][j].isalpha() and board[i][j].islower():
            key_set[board[i][j]] -= 1
        if board[i][j].isalpha() and board[i][j].isupper() and key_set[board[i][j].lower()] == 0:
            return
        visited[i][j] = True

        dfs(i - 1, j)
        dfs(i + 1, j)
        dfs(i, j - 1)
        dfs(i, j + 1)

        print('backtrack at {}, {}'.format(i, j))

        visited[i][j] = False

    i, j = start
    dfs(i, j)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    grid = ['...B\r', '.b#.\r', '@#+.\r']
    find_shortest_path(grid)
```

Now my problem is I need to return the path. For example, one of the results of this algorithm would be

```
[[2,0], [1,0], [1,1], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a parameter to `dfs` which takes the number of the step you currently process (which must be incremented by one when recursively calling `dfs`) and if you set the `visited` (sub)array with this step number (where e.g. 0 or -1 means "not visited") instead of boolean values, you can, when end is found, follow the numbered steps in the `visited` array.

This doesn't work if you have to step over the same position twice (e.g. if key is in a dead end and you have to go into to take it and back out to go to the door. But this wouldn't work with your current code either.